# libGDX Strange Dot in Box2DDebugRenderer

Tags: java, android, libgdx, box2d

I create `Body` object that cannot precision collide with ground. There are strange dot(.) between them.

Here the pic:
[image]
[image]

Here my script to create `Body` object:

```
BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
bodyDef.position.set(Static.toMeter(128), Static.toMeter(128));
bodyDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
body = world.createBody(bodyDef);

// Define mario shape
PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
shape.setAsBox(Static.toMeter(32) / 2, Static.toMeter(32) / 2);

FixtureDef fixture = new FixtureDef();
fixture.shape = shape;

body.createFixture(fixture);
body.setUserData(this);
```

Why this happen?

Did I create something wrong?

I checked some example online and didn't show the dot.

UPDATE:

```
public static final int WIDTH = 800;
public static final int HEIGHT = 600;
public static final float PIXEL_TO_METER = 1/300f;
public static final float METER_TO_PIXEL = 300;
```

Comment: Just to say it one last time: The dot is there since it is the contact with another body! Changing the resolution just makes the dot harder to see, but it is still there. Check the Mario game you seem to use, if you zoom into Mario you see the dot. If you don't want to see them, disable drawing contacts in the box2d debug renderer!

Answer (score 0):

By default the box2d debug renderer renders everything box2d, this means it renders fixtures, joints, etc., see the constructor:

```
new Box2DDebugRenderer(drawBodies, drawJoints, drawAABBs, drawInactiveBodies, drawVelocities, drawContacts);
```

This small dot is a contact.

Answer (score -1):

Basically I just set conversion to big. 300 pixel = 1 meter.

When I change it under 100 pixel = 1 meter. It works fine. So, I change to this:

```
public static final float PIXEL_TO_METER = 1/64f;
public static final float METER_TO_PIXEL = 64;
```

Comment: But the dot is still there, it is just not that prominent. Since it IS the contact. One can easily verify that by moving the body and every time it touches something you will see the dot. Otherwise its a good idea to not use pixels as box2d unit.